# What is the best way to get key-value in HTTP header request in ActionHero.js?

Tags: actionhero

To extract key-value in header of HTTP request sent to ActionHero.js server, I have to type long chain then split to get what I want

```
data.connection.rawConnection.req.rawHeaders....
```

Is there any better way to get such as

```
data.headers.key
```

Answer (score 1):

I found simpler way: use headers rather than rawHeaders

data.connection.rawConnection.req.headers